# How to find the specific BLE 4.0 peripheral from two devices with same service UUID

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

For BLE 4.0, it provides API to discover peripherals with array of service UUID.

I just want to find the specific one. How to achieve this ?

If need assign the identifier to the specific device, how to do it ?

(I think my question need some context of core bluetooth of iOS. )

Comment: did you find out the answer? I have the same situation. If you could share what you found that would be nice.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague: do you want to discover a new peripheral, or reconnect to a previously connected peripheral, or to discover a specific service on a discovered peripheral? It seems like Paulw11 has the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 5):

The process for reconnecting to known peripherals is described in the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW9).

Essentially if you know the UUID of the device you want to reconnect to (which is the `identifier` property of the `CBPeripheral` object) then you can use the `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method of the `CBCentralManager` to obtain the `CBPeripheral` object and then attempt a connection -

```
NSUUID *pid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"45D956BB-75E4-6CEB-C06C-D531B00174E4" ];
NSArray *peripherals=[self.centralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[pid]];
if ([peripherals count]>0)
{
      CBPeripheral *peripheral=[peripherals objectAtIndex:0];
      peripheral.delegate=self;
      [self.connectingPeripherals addObject:peripheral];

      NSLog(@"Found peripheral %@ with name %@",peripheral.identifier,peripheral.name);
      [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
 }
```

This may not work, and you may have to scan for your peripheral as the identifier of some peripherals (iOS devices in particular) periodically change their UUID.

The programming guide notes -

> Note: A peripheral device may not be available to be connected to for
>   a few reasons. For instance, the device may not be in the vicinity of
>   the central. In addition, some Bluetooth low energy devices use a
>   random device address that changes periodically. Therefore, even if
>   the device is nearby, the address of the device may have changed since
>   the last time it was discovered by the system, in which case the
>   CBPeripheral object you are trying to connect to doesn’t correspond to
>   the actual peripheral device. If you cannot reconnect to the
>   peripheral because its address has changed, you must rediscover it
>   using the scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: method.

You will also have to scan the first time you encounter a peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm wrong. You have 2 devices working as central role who wants to connect to one BLE peripheral.

What it is important is the UUID of the services in the BLE peripheral. From your devices in central role you should search peripherals with a wanted UUID Service. Thats all.

To develop with iOS please follow [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html). You have a good tutorial there.

As an example of the Apple documentation:

```
[myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

In this line of code you can add an Array of UUID objects (`CBUUID`) instead of nil for `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:`