# Differences between CBUUID and NSUUID in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Where are the differences between the CBUUID and the NSUUID object?

I have seen to fill the scanForPeripheralsWithServices with both objects in different cases... Apple expect an CBUUID object so I would prefer to use this type or?

My example:

`let MY_SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "hdl83h6sd-gl95-bn4f-37gd-jd73hd0tn8za")
func scanForPeripheralsWithServices(serviceUUIDs: MY_SERVICE_UUID,nil)`

Comment: Your cbuuid example is invalid - it must consist of hexadecimal numbers 0-9 a-f

Comment: I'm sorry about that! you are completely right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An NSUUID is a 128 bit number that is used to uniquely identify objects, types and other items. It can be accessed as bytes or is commonly used in a string form - 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067. The class includes methods for creating both random UUIDs and instances initialised with a specialised value.

Bluetooth also uses 128 bit identifiers for characteristics and services. The Bluetooth SIG has defined many "well known" services and characteristics. These are represented as a 16 bit value which is combined with the Bluetooth base UUID to get the full 128 bit value.

The CBUUID methods are aware of these well known values and can automatically transform the 16 bit values into their 128 bit equivalent. A CBUUID can also be initialised with a 128 bit value if you aren't using well known values (I.e. You have created your own private services and characteristics)

For example initialising a CBUUID with `CBUUID(string:"180F")` is ok (this is the battery service) but `NSUUID(string:"180F")` would fail because it needs all 128 bits.

When working with Core Bluetooth you will use CBUUID for services and characteristics. An NSUUID is used for the peripheral identifier since that is just a MAC with no special values defined.

Comment: Okay, so if I use a customized structure of services and characteristics with free created UUID's I should use a NSUUID number or? because in this case I don't have to convert a short 16 bit UUID into a 128 bits UUID. But do I have to take care about the expected input type of the scan method in this case? Thanks!

Comment: No, you should use CBUUID. The CBUUID initialisers will handle a 16 bit or 128 bit value. You will find that all Core Bluetooth functions now use CBUUID. There is an initialiser for CBUUID that takes an NSUUID if you did have one.

Comment: sorry to ask the following question in this area but I haven't got enough reputation to comment another answer of you... So I would like to know 2 things: 1. Why do Apple devices change their UUID's periodically? This question refers to your answer in this area: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778273/how-to-find-the-specific-ble-4-0-peripheral-from-two-devices-with-same-service-u 2. When I would like to search for only one specific UUID am I right to replace the option in scanforPeripheralsWithServices from nil to e.g. peripheral.identifier? or which UUID do I have to set there? Thankyou!

Comment: In other words, what UUID do I get from peripheral.identifier? :)

Comment: That is an NSUUID as it is just a MAC address and there are no well known 16 bit values

Comment: Ahh okay that might be the reason, why I was not able to scan for this specific value. I tried to search only for a specific MAC address in this case...So the option parameter of "scanforPeripheralsWithServices" supports only the knwon 16 bit UUID's, right? And if I would like to search for a specific device I have to filter that out in the DidDiscoverdPeripherl Methode.

Comment: You can scan for a 16 bit or a 128 bit service but this is different to the peripheral identifier. The identifier is the hardware address while the service is something that it advertises. For example all heart rate monitors will advertise the heart rate service but each will have a different unique identifier at the hardware level

Comment: Okay that's clear! So I think the specific UUID's for services and characteristics aren't send with the advertising (in Apple designed devices) or?

Comment: Some services will be advertised but not necessarily all. Once you connect to a peripheral you can discover if it offers additional services and the characteristics of those services. For example a heart rate monitor would probably offer battery and device info services as well as heart rate but would only advertise heart rate as that is how you would want to discover it and there is limited space in the advertisement packet